# Compare execution log's ignoring the execution times

Tags: bash, sed, diff

I'm new on linux SO and bash commands and i think someone with more experience could help me. I wanna compare 2 different text files with log's of an execution, but some lines (not all of them) begin with a time' token like this:

```
12345 ps line 1 content 
23456 ps line 2 content 
line 3 content 
345 ps line 4 content
```

Those tokens have different values in each log, but, in that comparison, i don't care about them, i wanna just to compare the line contents and ignore them. I could use 'sed' command to generate new files without that tokens and then comepare them, but i pretend to do that repeatedly and could save me some time if i use just one command or one sh file. I've tried to use 'sed' and 'diff' combined, but without success. Would anyone please be able to help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following sed one liner to remove the numbers from the beginning of the file:

```
sed 's/^[0-9]* ps//g' file1
```

To diff two such files (less timestamps) you can use [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html).

```
diff <(sed 's/^[0-9]* ps//g' file1) <(sed 's/^[0-9]* ps//g' file2)
```

Comment: And thanks too by the information about [process substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html)! It will be very usefull in my daily job.

Answer (score 0):

Untested since you didn't show 2 input files and the expected output but from your description I THINK this would do what you want:

```
awk '
   { sub(/^[[:digit:]]+[[:space:]]*/,"") }
   NR==FNR { file1[FNR] = $0; next }
   { print ($0 == file1[FNR] ? "==" : "!="), $0 }
' file1 file2
```

If that doesn't do it, post some small sample input and expected output.